# Drawing a Go-Board with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Might drawing a [Go-Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) be possible within matplotlib?
I will not show you my horrible tries (it included some working with patches) as long as you do not ask for them, I hope you come up with better ideas.

Or even better: there is a library for this, or someone already programmed it?
That would be nice!

(Why would someone need a GO Board within matplotlib? there are plenty of reasons. My AI works with python/C++ anyway as well as some visualizations of the performance, which is plotted in matplotlib. It is now possible to export/import to .sgf, but this includes an external viewer which is slow if there is the need for many plots. )

Comment: Probably, but I'd think that Pygame would be better (or just drawing it ASCII art style).

Answer (score 8):

Sure. Anything can be drawn, it is just a matter of amount of code required...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a 8" x 8" board
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8,8])
fig.patch.set_facecolor((1,1,.8))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# draw the grid
for x in range(19):
    ax.plot([x, x], [0,18], 'k')
for y in range(19):
    ax.plot([0, 18], [y,y], 'k')

# scale the axis area to fill the whole figure
ax.set_position([0,0,1,1])

# get rid of axes and everything (the figure background will show through)
ax.set_axis_off()

# scale the plot area conveniently (the board is in 0,0..18,18)
ax.set_xlim(-1,19)
ax.set_ylim(-1,19)

# draw Go stones at (10,10) and (13,16)
s1, = ax.plot(10,10,'o',markersize=30, markeredgecolor=(0,0,0), markerfacecolor='w', markeredgewidth=2)
s2, = ax.plot(13,16,'o',markersize=30, markeredgecolor=(.5,.5,.5), markerfacecolor='k', markeredgewidth=2)
```

Gives this:

[image]

If you do not like the background, you may even put there some nice photograph of a go board or whatever you need by using `imshow`.

One nice thing is that if you take the objects returned by `ax.plot`, you can remove them and replot the board without doing a lot of work.

```
ax.lines.remove(s1)
```

or simply

```
s1.remove()
```

The first one shows what is going on; the line object is removed from the line list, the second one is faster to type, as the line object knows its parent.

Either of this, and it's gone. (You may need to call `draw` to see the changes.)

---

There are many ways to do things in python, and `matplotlib` is no exception. As per `tcaswell`'s suggestions the the lines are replaced by the grid, and the circular markers with circle patches. Also, now black and white stones are created from prototypes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import copy

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8,8], facecolor=(1,1,.8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xticks=range(19), yticks=range(19), axis_bgcolor='none', position=[.1,.1,.8,.8])
ax.grid(color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(bottom='off', top='off', labelbottom='off')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(left='off', right='off', labelleft='off')

black_stone = mpatches.Circle((0,0), .45, facecolor='k', edgecolor=(.8,.8,.8, 1), linewidth = 2, clip_on=False, zorder=10)
white_stone = copy.copy(black_stone)
white_stone.set_facecolor((.9, .9, .9))
white_stone.set_edgecolor((.5, .5, .5))

s1 = copy.copy(black_stone)
s1.center = (18,18)
ax.add_patch(s1)

s2 = copy.copy(white_stone)
s2.center = (6,10)
ax.add_patch(s2)
```

The result is essentially the same.

Comment: It is even simpler, `s1.remove()` will do the right thing.  I would also use `ax_hline` and `ax_vilne` instead of plotting, or just hi-jack the grid system.  I would also use circle patches instead of plotting so you can control the size in a saner way

Comment: @tcaswell: Thank you for the comments! I agree with you, but I just tried to make code which uses as few less well-known features of `matplotlib`. I will try to integrate your suggestions into my answer somehow. (I actually thought of using the grid, and were it not for the corners and edges, it would've been a very simple solution.)

Comment: If you turn the clipping off on the artists you just use the axes frame as the outer edge

Comment: @tcaswell: Thanks, that I had not realized. I added a new example with this. Feel free to comment if there is something odd!

Comment: is it possible to add the coordinate labels on the side?